# Active Directory nested groups

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a C# 4.0 program working that retrieves all the members for a specific AD group. In this AD group are other AD groups containing other members. I need my program to identity that it is a group and retrieve the members in that group.

I know I need to write a recursive program but I was hoping somebody out there might have already done it.  If not, could somebody tell me the AD property attribute to identify that the member is actual a group?

Comment: This link can be useful: http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Retrieving_tokenGroups_from_ADAM

Answer (score 18):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJanuary2008en-us.chm)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD. Also: the `GroupPrincipal` has a method called `GetMembers` which will list all members of that group - optionally, it will do so recursively for you!

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find the group you're interested in
GroupPrincipal myGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeGroup");

// if you found it - get its members
if (myGroup != null)
{
   // if your call the GetMembers, you can optionally specify a "Recursive" flag - done here
   var allMembers = myGroup.GetMembers(true);
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Thank you for the tip on S.DS.AM.  It just saved me the pain of writing a recursive program!!!!

Comment: `GetMembers(true)` has a limitation, e.g. `Domain Users` are not returned at all. In order to get them you have to call `GetMembers(false)` recursively.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit what are the other limitation?

Comment: I don't know the exact difference between `GetMembers(true)` and `GetMembers(false)`. But I noticed "Domain Users" are not returned which drive me to use `false` rather than `true`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: that's probably the so-called "primary group" that is in fact never returned by any of those "GetMembers" calls ...

Comment: @marc_s When using the optional recursive flag is there a way to know what nested group the user inherited membership to the parent group through please?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using the LDAP view into ActiveDirectory, the attribute you're looking for is called "objectClass".  A group shows up with an objectClass of "groupOfNames", I believe; possibly "group".  Alternatively, just look to see if the object has any "member"s, regardless of object class, and if it does, assume it's some sort of group and recurse.