# Check Authorization on ActiveDirectory Object

Tags: c#, .net, security, active-directory, authorization

I want to test if an arbitrary user has write-access to attributes of a particular Active Directory object.  I think one part of the solution appears to be this:

```
NTAccount Account = new NTAccount("Domain\\XYZ");
SecurityIdentifier Sid =
(SecurityIdentifier)Account.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
```

That seems to allow me to get a concrete representation from a string representation of the user.  Another piece of the puzzle I think is this:

```
string strMemberString = "LDAP://OU=Test,DC=Domain,DC=local";
DirectoryEntry computers = new DirectoryEntry();
computers.Path = strMemberString;
computers.Options.SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Owner | SecurityMasks.Group
| SecurityMasks.Dacl | SecurityMasks.Sacl;

foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
{
   if (computer.Name == "CN=Test")
   {
      ActiveDirectorySecurity sdc = computer.ObjectSecurity;
      //...
```

Not sure where to go from there.  How do I finish this?  Is there an entirely different way I should be pursuing?  I'm using .net 4.0.

I'd prefer that the solution be entirely BCL code, rather than PInvoke or WMI.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that "having write access to attributes of aparticular Active-Directory object" can result from the belonging of a group or a group which belongs to a group and so on?

Comment: @JPBlanc: Yes, I am aware.  That "work" should be handled for me by the BCL.  I just need to understand the usage story.

Comment: I edited my answer, you'll find there the way to retreive the security groups a user is bellonging to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to look for a class that gives the "Effective Rights" as represented in a tab of the advanced dialog box in the security tab of an AD object :

[image]

It exists also a command line tool called [ACLDiag.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786928%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that do what you want.

---

(Edited)
To find groups a user belongs to you can

- Write a recursive query program, It gives bad performance in big organizations.
- Use of a special matching rule called "LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN" (See [Search Filter Syntax for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I give an example in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252819/find-recursive-group-membership-active-directory-using-c/6289205#6289205). It's a bit long too, but as far as I know, it's the only way to retreive security AND distribution groups.
- use the '[tokenGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)' attribute. It'is a computed attribute which holds the ids of every SecurityGroup the user is a member of, including the indirect groups. I think this the one you can use and that is provided with the [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method (in the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace and introduced in .Net 3.5)

Comment: I'm looking for a programmatic solution, rather than an administrative solution, but thanks for this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the allowedAttributesEffective attribute.

Comment: [Allowed-Attributes-Effective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675218(v=VS.85).aspx) is the list of attributes that can be modified on the object

Comment: I was thinking that he was looking for ACLs on attributes.