# Enumeration of nested AD user groups using C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, group-membership

I've written some code that gets all users of groups and nested groups. I also wanted to make sure that looping did not happen if the group membership caused a loop by having the first group a member of the last group.

The code I wrote works OK but is a little slow.

This is the first time I've tried to do AD look-ups.

Could someone take a look and tell me if the code looks OK or bad-coding (or worse), or I've gone about it the wrong way?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;

namespace Tester3
{
    class Program3
    {
        public static List<string> appGroupList = new List<string>();        
        public static List<string> userList = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> groupList = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> groupChecked = new List<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create Output File
            StreamWriter outputfile = new StreamWriter("output.txt", false);

            appGroupList.Add("GLB-SBCCitrixHelpdesk-DL");
            appGroupList.Add("SBC_UKBSAVIA001_PROD_ROL_Siebel");

            foreach (string appGroup in appGroupList)
            {
                string appGroupCN = GetCN(appGroup);

                GetMembers(appGroupCN);

                groupChecked.Clear();
            }

            foreach (string item in userList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                outputfile.WriteLine(item);
            }

            outputfile.Flush();
            outputfile.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetCN(string group)
        {
            string groupCN = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher())
                {
                    search.Filter = "(&(cn=" + group + ")(objectClass=group))";
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");
                    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        groupCN = result.Properties["adsPath"][0].ToString();
                        groupCN = groupCN.Replace("LDAP://", "");
                    }

                    return groupCN;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return groupCN;
            }
        }

        public static void GetMembers(string group) // get members using the groups full cn 
        {
            // Check if group has already been checked
            if (groupChecked.Contains(group))
            {
                return;
            }

            // Add group to groupChecked list
            groupChecked.Add(group);

            try
            {
                // Connect to group object
                using (DirectoryEntry groupObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + group))
                {
                    // Get member of group object
                    PropertyValueCollection col = groupObject.Properties["member"] as PropertyValueCollection;

                    // Loop through each member
                    foreach (object member in col)
                    {
                        // Connect to member object
                        using (DirectoryEntry memberObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + member))
                        {
                            // Get class of member object
                            string memberClass = memberObject.Properties["objectClass"][1].ToString();
                            string memberCN = memberObject.Properties["Name"][0].ToString();

                            if (!groupChecked.Contains(member.ToString()))
                            {
                                if (memberClass.ToLower() == "group")
                                {                                    
                                    GetMembers(member.ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    userList.Add(memberCN);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (memberClass.ToLower() != "group")
                                {
                                    userList.Add(memberCN);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look to [this answer][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252819/find-recursive-group-membership-active-directory-using-c/6289205#6289205

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // get a user's group memberships 
   foreach(Principal principal in me.GetGroups())
   {
       GroupPrincipal gp = (principal as GroupPrincipal);

       if(gp != null)
       {
           // do something with the group
       }
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD. The call to `.GetGroups()` also handles all the problems of nested group memberships and so forth for you - no need to deal with that hassle anymore!

Comment: I did look at the newer .Net 3.5 code but my end application will have to work on servers that only have .net 2.0 installed.

Comment: @RickBowden: but .NET 3.5 is just a small "service pack" on top of .NET 2.0 - nothing totally new......

Comment: That's true, but I work in such a tightly (overly) managed change controlled environment that upgrading these things is a nightmare.

Comment: @RickBowden: maybe it helps if you can explain to your boss that if you can use .NET 3.5, you'll have it done in 2 hours, while without it, you'll need two or three days.. ....