# Get currently logged in Windows user?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the groups of a user in Active Directory? (c#, asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net)

Is there a way get the currently logged on user using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace? I've been using the following:

```
    Dim wi As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

    Dim fullName As String = wi.Name.ToString

    Dim loggedOnUser = fullName.Substring(fullName.IndexOf("\") + 1)

    Console.WriteLine("The currently logged on user is {0}", loggedOnUser)
```

But I want more information about the current user, like the group names they belong to in plain text, and was wondering if the `AccountManagement` namespace provides this.

Using this just returns strings of numbers that I can't make sense of:

```
For Each item As IdentityReference In wi.Groups
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: "I want more information about the current user ": what kind of information?

Comment: What kind of information do you want more? The WindowsIdentity-object returned from GetCurrent() contains more info than only a Name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified. I need to get the group names they belong to in plain text and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.groups.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you searching for something like that?

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "login");
    foreach (var group in user.GetGroups())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.Name);
    }
}
```

edit: found it with a little help of google at stackoverflow ;-)
[Active directory : get groups where a user is member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305279/active-directory-get-groups-where-a-user-is-member)