# Getting Groups recursively for user always gives different results

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am currently working on a part of an authorization system in our product and we have a problem with getting all groups a user is in (including nested groups).

The User `MyUser` is in the following groups:
    `GroupA`
    `GroupB`

`GroupB` is a member of `GroupC`, and `GroupC` is a member of `GroupD`.
My desired Output would be: `GroupA, GroupB, GroupC, GroupD`.

With my code, I somehow get different results for the exact same user almost every time I run my queries.
The results vary from the complete list, to only the first level or just the `GroupD` missing.

My code is as following.
The part where I am parsing the string with `IndexOf` is just to get the group name itself because the returned value is something like `CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,OU=XYZ,DC=abc,DC=XXX`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var groups = new List<string>();
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(...);
    GetGroupsRecursively("MyUser", groups, searcher);
}

private static void GetGroupsRecursively(string group, List<string> groups, DirectorySearcher search)
{
    search.Filter = string.Format("(cn={0})", group);
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");

    var searchResults = search.FindAll();
    foreach (SearchResult result in searchResults)
    {
        foreach (var dn in result.Properties["memberof"].Cast<string>())
        {
            var equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);

            if (equalsIndex != -1)
            {
                var commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                var subGroup = dn.Substring(equalsIndex + 1, commaIndex - equalsIndex - 1);
                if (!groups.Contains(subGroup))
                {
                    groups.Add(subGroup);
                    GetGroupsRecursively(subGroup, groups, search);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my way of getting the groups? (Please do not suggest to use the `PrincipalContext` or the like, because we can't use them here.)

**Could this be a configuration issue with the AD-Server?**

Comment: Are you getting different results for the same user or for different users that are members of the same groups?

Comment: I get different results for the exact same user. I'm pointing that out in the question now.

Comment: This is not the cleanest way to do that, have a look to [Check active directory group membership recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145781/check-active-directory-group-membership-recursively/10151147#10151147)

Comment: What looks really strange here is that you are using the same searcher, instead of creating a new one each time...

Comment: @JPBlanc Thanks for your suggestion, but as I pointed out we cannot use the PrincipalContext.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco What would you suggest is the best way to create a new searcher? I am curious as I do not know with what values the constructor would be called.

Comment: So try [Find Recursive Group Membership (Active Directory) using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6289205/608772).

Comment: This solution does NOT work. I don't know why, since I do know nothing about the AD-server which I'm targeting.