# How to get the nested groups in LDAP/AD?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We have an LDAP login problem of a specific user and I'm suspecting that this is due to cyclic groups assignment in LDAP, i.e. the user is assigned to groups A,B,C,D. Group A contains sub-groups E,F,G and group E contains group A again.

If I query for the user I can see that he has been assigned with 50+ groups and each group may contain more groups and each of those may contain more....

My question is if there's a query I can run to get the nested groups inside those main groups all the way down instead of going each group and do it manually?

The server is AD

[image]

Comment: I have just started using LDAP and Active Directory - here is a post that I think might help. [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114909-Find-all-sub-groups-of-all-depths-of-a-given-group-in-LDAP-using-LdapTemplate)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the expression doesn't compile: (&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4. 19 41:={0})) If I replace {0} with the user's distinguishedName I am getting missing colon....

Comment: Looking at the Microsoft MSDN page has this tid bit. Similarly, to find all the groups that "user1" is a member of, set the base to the groups container DN; for example (OU=groupsOU, dc=x) and the scope to subtree, and use the following filter. (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)). I don't know if this would show that the user is part of group A twice because of a nesting issue.

Comment: I am actually using Apache Directory Studio to query AD...

Answer (score 4):

To find all the groups that "user1" is a member of (adaptation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289205/608772) answer see [AD search filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

- Set the base to the groups container DN; for example root DN (dc=dom,dc=fr)
- Set the scope to subtree
- Use the following filter : (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)

**Example** with LDIFDE.EXE (native command line AD search on windows) :

```
ldifde -f t.txt -d "DC=dom,DC=fr" -r "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=jblanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr)"
```

**Remark** : as far as I remember there is a small syntax difference with in brackets user DN name. '1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941' is not working in W2K3 SP1, it begins to work with SP2. I presume it's the same with W2K3 R2. I test here with W2K8R2.

With Apache Directory Studio :
[image: Apache LDAP recursive query in AD]

Result :

[image: Apache LDAP recursive query result in AD]

Comment: Thanks.
If I set the base search to: DC=comp1,DC=ad,DC=comp,DC=com
And the search filter to:member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=lastName, firstName,OU=Users,OU=SUN,OU=rEU,OU=Client,DC=comp1,DC=ad,DC=comp,DC=com) then I get no results. I selected subtree and I know this user has groups assigned. Any idea...?

Comment: have you really got a coma between lastName and firstName ? If so, just try `...CN=lastName\\, firstName,OU=Users...`

Comment: Changed to \\, but still not getting results unfortunately :(
Anything else I might be doing wrong....?

Comment: Can you give your full filter ? and the exact DN of your user.

Comment: Uploaded an image, see above. For data protection I have renamed the organisation name with ab and ab1 and the person's name with firstName lastName

Comment: Strange now I am getting results back but only 14 where this user has 50+ groups not including the nested ones.

Comment: What kind of groups (security, distribution) from which domain?

Comment: All groups are from the same domain: DC=ab1,DC=ad,DC=ab,DC=com. The groups seems to be security groups (Mix of Global security groups, Domain local security groups and Universal security groups)