# How to fix ADOQuery request

Tags: delphi, active-directory, ldap-query

I have this ADOQuery:

```
SQL.Text := 'SELECT samAccountName FROM ''GC://' + sADForestName + ''' ' +
            'WHERE objectCategory=''user'' ' +
              'AND distinguishedName=''' + sADUserName + ''' ' +
              'AND memberOf=''' + sADGroupName + '''';
```

And this is work fine to get group for user, 
but I need also check nested groups using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN:

```
SQL.Text := 'SELECT samAccountName FROM ''GC://' + sADForestName + ''' ' +
            'WHERE objectCategory=''user'' ' +
              'AND distinguishedName=''' + sADUserName + ''' ' +
              'AND memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=''' + sADGroupName + '''';
```

But this request does not executed, I'm got error when calling ADOQuery.Open; 
(translated from Russian): "There was one or more errors while processing the command"

This is my error with request?

Comment: one of the possible sources of error are the colons near memberOf, which could be avoided by setting ParamCheck to false.

Comment: but in all samples I see this: (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=Group1,OU=groupsOU,DC=x)

Comment: @bummi is suggesting switching off the `ParamCheck` property of TADOQuery, not changing your SQL. Delphi may be thinking :1.2.... is a parameter which will break your SQL. Turning off ParamCheck will stop this second-guessing. Code samples in other languages may not have the same problem handling colons(:) in SQL, as they tend to use other characters to mark parameters

Comment: Understand now, but with ParamCheck=False I have the same error :(

Comment: @AlexEgorov: please, provide one of those samples your told about. Let us compare what should be done with what was actualy done.

Comment: some samples: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252819/find-recursive-group-membership-active-directory-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @AlexEgorov: that links shows how to do it with native LDAP requests. That's not the same thing what you are trying to do here.

Comment: But how I can do that in delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all guys, I found decision using ADOCommand:

```
var ADOConnection, ADOCmd, Res: Variant;

    ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    ADOCmd := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
    try
      ADOConnection.Provider := 'ADsDSOObject';
      ADOConnection.Open('Active Directory Provider');
      ADOCmd.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
      ADOCmd.Properties('Page Size')     := 100;
      ADOCmd.Properties('Timeout')       := 30;
      ADOCmd.Properties('Cache Results') := False;

      sBase       := '<GC://' + sADForestName+ '>';
      sFilter     := '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)' +
                       '(distinguishedName=' + sADUserName + ')' +
                       '(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' + sADGroupName + '))';
      sAttributes := 'sAMAccountName';

      ADOCmd.CommandText := sBase + ';' + sFilter + ';' + sAttributes + ';subtree';
      Res := AdoCmd.Execute;

      if Res.EOF then User := ''
                 else User := Res.Fields[0].Value;
    finally
      ADOCmd := NULL;
      ADOConnection.Close;
      ADOConnection := NULL;
    end;
```