# Powershell connecting and searching multiple domains

Tags: powershell, active-directory, quest

I am trying to locate the group memberships for a specified user account.  One domain's user account is often a member of a group in the other domains (some domains require different admin account).   Using get-QAQgroup, I can successfully search each domain individually, but when I try to loop through the domains, I can only find results in the domain that I am logged into. 
    #Script to change domains and look for group memberships for a specified user account.

```
$domains = "dom1.ad.state.company.com","dom2.ad.state.company.com","dom3.ad.state.company.com","dom4.ad.state.company.com","corporate.state.company.com","OddNamedDom.com"
$CRED=GET-CREDENTIAL
$userAcc = read-host "Enter domain\username for Group Membership Search"

foreach ($domain in $domains)
  {
     write-host "In the domain $domain "," $userAcc is a direct member of..."
     Get-QADGroup -service $domain -Credential $cred -Containsmember $userAcc | select name
  } #foreach domain

Connect-QADService -Service 'dom1.ad.state.company.com'
```

When I run the script I get results for dom1 (domain I am logged into) and the rest throw the following errors.  I am not sure why the "Ref 1:.." lines are pointing to 'dom1'.  I thought that might be the source of issue.  I have copied the Powershell output below showing the error messages.

```
In the domain dom1.ad.state.company.com   dom1\brownd2.admin.dom1 is a direct member of...

Name                                                                                                                                            
----                                                                                                                                        
DOM1-G-ITS-DS-Company Services                                                                                                                 
DOM1PGUELFP00003-Exmerge-R                                                                                                                   
DOMPGUELFP00003-Exmerge-C                                                                                                                   
ITSPPTBOSHFS003-FSSHARE-C                                                                                                                   
Domain Users                                                                                                                                

In the domain dom2.ad.state.company.com   dom1\brownd2.admin.dom1 is a direct member of...
Get-QADGroup : 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-03100742, data 0, 1 access points
    ref 1: 'dom1.ad.state.company.com'
At C:\TestScripts\tGet-UserAllMemberships.ps1:24 char:6
+      Get-QADGroup -service $domain -Credential $cred -Containsmember $userAcc |  ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-QADGroup], DirectoryAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.DirectoryAccess.DirectoryAccessException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShel 
   lSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.GetGroupCmdlet

In the domain dom3.ad.state.company.com   dom1\brownd2.admin.dom1 is a direct member of...
Get-QADGroup : 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-03100742, data 0, 1 access points
    ref 1: 'dom1.ad.state.company.com'
At C:\TestScripts\tGet-UserAllMemberships.ps1:24 char:6
+      Get-QADGroup -service $domain -Credential $cred -Containsmember $userAcc |  ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-QADGroup], DirectoryAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.DirectoryAccess.DirectoryAccessException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShel 
   lSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.GetGroupCmdlet
```

There is a similar set of errors for each domain that I am checking.  I have not posted the full list of error messages.

If I change the order of the domains in the array, the errors and the results of the one successful domain just change order to match the array.  I thought that it might just be successful for the first iteration of the loop.  Not the case though.

I know that the account is a member of groups in Dom2 and not in any groups in Dom3.  If I take the commands out of the foreach loop and run individual for each domain in the console I do get the expected results.  Based on the individual results, I had thought that this would be straight forward example to do in a loop, but I am not connecting correctly to the domains.

What can I change?

Comment: What is your version of PowerShell ? Are all domain in the same Forest ? Do you consider using Global Catalog ?

Comment: Powershell is version 4.  Yes, all in the same forest, there is a parent (root) domain with several child domains.  As for the global catalog, I am not sure how I would apply a solution using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299745.aspx) Namespace, adapted to PowerShell from C# code. It's a kind of recursive solution. In [Find Recursive Group Membership (Active Directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289205/608772) using C#, I give a recursive solution (using basic ADSI avaible from PowerShell 1.0) that also works with distribution groups.

```
# Retreiving a principal context for the administrator on the Global Catalog
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$domainContext = New-Object DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, "VMESS01:3268" , "administrator", "adminPasswd")
# Retreive the groups
try {
  $userPrincipal = [DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($domainContext, "jpb")
  $groups = $userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
  foreach($group in $groups)
  {
    $group.name;
  }
}
finally {
    $pc.domainContext()
}
```