# Getting error while finding AD Groups of a user using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, vb.net, userprincipal, principalcontext, adgroup

I have a situation where I need to find AD groups of a user recursively.

For Example :

```
I have such group hierarchy -
Group1
  |_
    Group2
      |_
        Group3
         |_
           UserA
```

According to the hierarchy, Groups of UserA are Group1, Group2, Group3

For finding it through the code I have used following method :

```vb
Dim UserP1 As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Remote_ID)
allrecursiveUserGroups = UserP1.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```

This method would give me all the groups recursively, but it is failing for one user and giving the exception as follows:

> 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException'
>   occurred in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
>
> Additional information: While trying to retrieve the authorization
>   groups, an error (1358) occurred.

Here is the complete StackTrace :

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException
>   was unhandled   ErrorCode=0   HResult=-2146233087   Message=While
>   trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (1358) occurred.
>   Source=System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet..ctor(Byte[]
>   userSid, NetCred credentials, ContextOptions contextOptions, String
>   flatUserAuthority, StoreCtx userStoreCtx, Object userCtxBase)
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOfAZ(Principal
>   p)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()

Another method which I used is :

```vb
Dim UserP1 As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Remote_ID)
Dim grps = UserP1.GetGroups
```

This is not throwing any exception and running perfectly for all Users but it only returns immediate groups i.e. Group3 in my case

The problem that I am facing with GetAuthorisationGroups is presence of special characters in Distinguished Name that I got by UserPrincipal.

The problem here is when [Distinguished Name][2] of `UserPrincipal` contains special characters (a comma in my case) then it throws exception.
In my case the distinguished name is :

> CN=Smith\, John,DC=mydomain,DC=com

Here backward slash has been used as escape character which is added by `UserPrincipal` itself.

If [Distinguished Name][2] doesn't contain any special character the function [GetAuthorizationGroups()][1] works fine.
e.g.

> CN=Smith John,DC=mydomain,DC=com

What is the reason of the problem and is there any solution available for this?

What am I missing in my First Approach of using `GetAuthorizationGroups()` method?

What is the reason for error code 1358?

Is there any other good way of finding groups recursively other than `GetAuthorisationGroups()` of class `UserPrincipal`

Comment: Is this of help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252819/find-recursive-group-membership-active-directory-using-c-sharp

Comment: ERROR_INTERNAL_DB_CORRUPTION
1358 (0x54E)
Unable to complete the requested operation because of either a catastrophic media failure or a data structure corruption on the disk.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jdweng what does datastructure corruption on disk can mean?

Comment: You may have a link on the disk from a child folder to parent so you are in an endless loop.  You may not have the proper credentials to read the folder/file.  Or may be the the sector of the disk is actually bad

Comment: But when I am using GetGroups() method then it is working fine but not in case of GetAuthorizationGroups(). How this is possible in case of dsk failure

Comment: I get an exception enumerating the groups returned by `GetAuthorizationGroups` whether or not the account name has a comma in it or not. But I get a different error.

Comment: Do you really need to list them all? Or are you really interested in only one group? There are other ways to figure out if a user is a member of a single group.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, I need to list all the groups in hierarchy. Single Level groups won't work for me.