# UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups() throwing exception when Distinguished Name in UserPrincipal contains special characters (a comma in my case)

Tags: c#, vb.net, userprincipal, principalcontext, adgroup

I have a situation where I need to find AD Group of a user recursively.
e.g. UserA is part of Group3, Group3 is part of Group2, Group2 is part of Group1
So, UserA is part of Group3, Group2, Group1.

Now, to find all the groups for a user I have used [GetAuthorizationGroups()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups(v=vs.110).aspx) in my code.

```vb
Dim UserP1 As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Remote_ID)
allrecursiveUserGroups = UserP1.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```

The problem here is when [Distinguished Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.distinguishedname(v=vs.110).aspx) of `UserPrincipal` contains special characters (a comma in my case) then it throws exception.
In my case the distinguished name is :

> CN=Smith\, John,DC=mydomain,DC=com

Here backward slash has been used as escape character which is added by `UserPrincipal` itself.

If [Distinguished Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.distinguishedname(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't contain any special character the function [GetAuthorizationGroups()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups(v=vs.110).aspx) works fine.
e.g.

> CN=Smith John,DC=mydomain,DC=com

What is the reason of the problem and is there any solution available for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error while finding AD Groups of a user using PrincipalContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350825/getting-error-while-finding-ad-groups-of-a-user-using-principalcontext)

Comment: Your other question has more details. You're better off updating your other question to include the fact that it happens only for accounts with commas in the name.